# MVC Replace Date in Controller with Empty String

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

In my MVC Project I have a Controller that returns store information and one of the fields is a Closed date. Im my sql, any date that is NULL is automatically returning a value of 1900-01-01. How do I get my Controller to replace that value with an empty string when its null. Thanks!

```
  activeStores = (from a in activeStoreResult.ActiveStoresInfo
                            select new ActiveStoresViewModel
                            {
                                Store  = a.Store
                                Closed =  a.Closed 
                            }).ToList();
```

Comment: Need more info. You cannot interchange a DateTime field with a string field, you can make the DateTime field nullable `DateTime?` and use null instead of an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`1900-01-01` is the `DateTime.MinValue` which represents the smallest possible value of `DateTime`. You can check whether your `Closed` property gets this value and then replace it with `null`. Obviously your `ActiveStoresViewModel.Closed` datetime must be nullable.

```
activeStores = (from a in activeStoreResult.ActiveStoresInfo
                                select new ActiveStoresViewModel
                                {
                                    Store  = a.Store
                                    Closed =  a.Closed != DateTime.MinValue ? a.Closed : null
                                }).ToList();
```